# Java: Incompatible Types (int/boolean)

Tags: java, boolean, int, incompatibletypeerror

```
import java.io.*;
public class AdamHmwk4 {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int counter1;
        int counter2;
        int counter3;
        String answer = "";

        System.out.println("Welcome to Adam's skip-counting program!");
        System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to skip count by.");
        counter1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to start at.");
        counter2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to stop at.");
        counter3 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("This is skip counting by" + counter1 + ", starting at" + counter2  + "and ending at" + counter3 +":");

        while (counter2 = counter3) {
            counter2 = counter2 + counter1;
            counter3 = counter2 + counter1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make skip-counting program. When I compile this code, the line `while(counter2 = counter3){` shows up as a Incompatible Types error. The compiler says it found an "int" but it requires a "boolean". Please keep in mind that I am a newbie, so I have not learned booleans in my Java class yet.

Comment: How would I make the while loop into a proper loop? Right now after applying Mik378's fix, the loop does not activate.

Comment: What are the current values for `counter2` and `counter3` if you put a breakpoint at the `while` line?

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare values with `=`, which is the assignment operator.  Use `==` to compare your values.  Change

```
while(counter2 = counter3){
```

to

```
while(counter2 == counter3){
```

Here's an [introductory page for Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 1):

You use an assignment operator:

```
while(counter2 = counter3)
```

instead of the equality operator:

```
while(counter2 == counter3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
               while(counter2 = counter3)
```

`=` is used for assignment and post this statement, counter2 will be assigned the value of counter3. Hence your while loop will not behave the way you want. You need to use `==` for comparing counter2 to counter 3

```
               while(counter2 == counter3)
```